# Help on a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Consider a question, that **$\overline{xyxyxyxy}$** cannot be a **perfect square**. How should i tackle this problem. All i use is it must be $0,1 ($mod $3,4)$ and then the math, are there any another beatiful ways because this method does not work everytime.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your number is $xy \cdot 1010101$.  Can you find a factor that cannot be repeated?

Comment: Another approach is to use the divisibility test for $11$  and then some case checking.But your method is definitely more elegant.Although I'm not sure this "works every time",but what does?

Comment: Thank u for the beatiful answer, but i wanted to know how to tackle(different approaches) questions like this

Comment: @Shobhit,can you be more explicit?I am not sure what the definition of "problems like this" is.You gain the ability to solve  problems through experience.Not everything has a general method.

Comment: @Shobhit:  when you have digit patterns, it is often useful to represent them algebraically.  Sometimes it would help to replace $xy$ by $(10x+y)$  One general thing from this answer is if you have $1+x+x^2+\dots x^n$ with $n+1=pq$ you can always factor it as $(1+x+x^2+\dots x^{p-1})(1+x^p+x^{2p}+\dots x^{p(q-1)}$.  If $p \neq q$ that gives two different factorizations.